# Hide and show div and buttons based on id pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm working on a bunch of django forms that I would like to show one after the other once the former one has been submitted.

I had a look at the question: [jQuery - Function to display next element on page and hide the current one on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353286/jquery-function-to-display-next-element-on-page-and-hide-the-current-one-on-cl)

But I couldn't manage to have it work with what I have. :(

I put an example below of the html generated.
What I am trying to achieve:

1. Start by only displaying **div="question_2"** and **button id="submit_2"**. => DONE
2. Once I click on **button id="submit_2"** I want all **div** and **button** whose id ends with the following number (ie 3 here) to be displayed. In the below example I want **"question_3"** and **"submit_3"** to be displayed (and the following time: **"description_4"**, **"question_4"** and **"submit_4"**).
3. I want to hide **button id="submit_2"** so that at each step there is only one submit button at the very end of the webpage.
4. Ideally, I would like to hide the forms that have already been submitted. But I still want them to be displayed on the same page.

   This is a dummy introduction text.

   ```
   <div id="question_2" class="card" style="display: block;">
       <h5 class="card-header">Question 1</h5>
       <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-title">The first question is:</h6>
       <p class="card-text">
           <ul id="id_Question 1">
           <li><label for="id_Question 1_0"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 1" value="A" id="id_Question 1_0">Answer 1</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 1_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 1" value="B" id="id_Question 1_1">Answer 2</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 1_2"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 1" value="C" id="id_Question 1_2">Answer 3</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 1_3"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 1" value="D" id="id_Question 1_3">Answer 4</label></li>
           </ul>
       </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <button id="submit_2" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block;"/>Submit</button>

   <div id="question_3" class="card" style="display: block;">
       <h5 class="card-header">Question 2</h5>
       <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-title">The second question is:</h6>
       <p class="card-text">
           <ul id="id_Question 2">
           <li><label for="id_Question 2_0"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 2" value="A" id="id_Question 2_0">Answer 1</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 2_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 2" value="B" id="id_Question 2_1">Answer 2</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 2_2"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 2" value="C" id="id_Question 2_2">Answer 3</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 2_3"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 2" value="D" id="id_Question 2_3">Answer 4</label></li>
           </ul>
       </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <button id="submit_3" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block;"/>Submit</button>

    <div id="description_4" class="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3" style="display: none;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">This is an intermediary description.</h6>
        </div>
    </div>         

    <div id="question_4" class="card" style="display: block;">
       <h5 class="card-header">Question 3</h5>
       <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-title">The third question is:</h6>
       <p class="card-text">
           <ul id="id_Question 3">
           <li><label for="id_Question 3_0"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 3" value="A" id="id_Question 3_0">Answer 1</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 3_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 3" value="B" id="id_Question 3_1">Answer 2</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 3_2"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 3" value="C" id="id_Question 3_2">Answer 3</label></li>
           <li><label for="id_Question 3_3"><input type="checkbox" name="Question 3" value="D" id="id_Question 3_3">Answer 4</label></li>
           </ul>
       </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <button id="submit_4" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block;"/>Submit</button>
   ```

My jquery code:

```
{% block custom_js %}
<script>
    $( "#submit_2" ).click(function() {
        $( "div:hidden" ).first().fadeIn( "slow" );
        }
    )  
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

It does what I want only for the very first steps. Being a beginner in jquery, I don't know how to fadeIn everything that ends with _3, ...

Would have any idea of how I could achieve that?

Thank your for your help! :D

**UPDATE on 09/02/2020**: I'm making progress. My jquery code now looks like:

```
<script>
    var count = 2;

    function incrementCount(){
       count++;
    }

    $( "#submit_" + count.toString() ).click(function() {

        // Make current question read only + hide the submit button.
        $("div[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").prop('readonly', true);
        $("button[id$='_" + (count).toString() + "']").fadeOut( "slow" );

        incrementCount();

        // Display next question and associated submit button.
        $("div[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );
        $("button[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );


        }
    )
</script>
```

I have essentially two problems :

1. the function $( "#submit_" + count.toString() ).click(function() does not update when count is incremented. As a result it only works for the 1st click.
2. the read only does not work.

Would you have an idea for (1)? Could it be because jquery cannot cope with dynamic functions names?